# HTML package, useful to put htmlonly and latexonly environments, not found

Tags: html, latex2html

In the 2008 documentation of `latex2html` it is referred to a `html` package that permits to put some latex command inside conditional environments (`latexonly` and `htmlonly`).
It's useful because I want my latex source to be universal, and function for PDF creation and for HTML creation too.
Unfortunately there's no `html` package on CTAN, and no documentation on the Internet, and TeXlive 2012 seems not to include it, so that the command `\usepackage{html}` is rejected.
Anyone knows how to solve?

Comment: Do you mean [this file](http://www.tex.ac.uk/ctan/support/ltx2x/html.sty).  It has the environments you mention, but it looks pretty old to me....

Comment: I found that the html.sty files was in some directories of texlive installation. It was necessary to put it in another directory where LaTeX were capable to see it. Now it's ok, but I have discovered that htmlonly and latexonly are not enough: I need to differentiate the first line of the source code, changing memoir class to book class for compatibility with latex2html, for example... how to do it elegantly? Thanks and sorry for the poor english.

Comment: Can you post a minimal example file that you want to convert (but which won't convert correctly).  I often use the `memoir` class, so I may be able to help.

Comment: Hallo John.The error say that memoir.cls is not available and latex2html stops. Are you saying it's compatible? In that case I'll do some test to better identify the problem and I'll post here my deductions.

Comment: No, probably not: `latex2html` is not actively developed anymore.  A much better solution is `tex4ht`'s suite of conversion tools (which is what I have some experience).  However, I thought `latex2html` could handle simple `memoir` documents, but it seems that it cannot.  (Sorry for the false hope.)

Comment: I will study tex4ht in the future. Thanks.

Comment: Is the question how to make a .tex file that conditionally includes `\usepackage{html}` somehow?

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in comments, `latex4html` is not developed any more, so it's unlikely it will be possible to find this file (which is n any case very generically named and so hard to track down). You will be best looking at `tex4ht` as an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

**Update (2017):** There now is a new version latex2html-2017.2 available on [CTAN](https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/latex2html/).

**Outdated Answer:**
While latex2html is not longer in development, the package source can still be found online at http://www.latex2html.org/node6.html (last change in September 2001).  The file you are looking for is [here](http://www.latex2html.org/~latex2ht/user/texinputs/html.sty).  You can just copy this file into the directory where your own TeX file lives and include it using

```
\usepackage{html}
```

That said, given that the file has not been updated in more than a decade, it is probably a good idea to look into using a newer alternatives, *e.g.* [`tex4ht`](https://www.tug.org/applications/tex4ht/mn.html).

Comment: Not available at the moment!